# Changing properties of a dynamic component created by component factory does not affect HTML

Tags: angular

I want to generate HTML and open it in a new window to print. I have a component that should generates the HTML:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
import { RelocateResponseVm } from "src/contracts/warehouse/relocateResponseVm";

@Component({
    selector: 'transition-print',
    styleUrls: ['./transition.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    templateUrl: './transition.print.component.html'
})
export class TransitionPrintComponent {
    public data: RelocateResponseVm;

    constructor() { }
}
```

Its template is:

```
<ng-container>
    <div>
        <h1>Operation №{{data.Id}}</h1>
        <p>Date: <b>{{data.OperationDate}}</b></p>
        <p>Name: <b>{{data.Name}}</b></p>
        <p>Description: <b>{{data.Description}}</b></p>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

I create an instance of the component by the following code:

```
        const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TransitionPrintComponent);
        let componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);
        componentRef.instance.data = relocateDoc;

        console.log(componentRef.location.nativeElement);
```

Despite the `relocateDoc` is filled the `nativeElement` is empty:

```
<transition-print>
<!---->
<div>
<h1>Operation №</h1>
<p>Date: <b></b></p>
<p>Name: <b></b></p>
<p>Description: <b></b></p>
</div>
</transition-print>
```

What is the problem? How to fill the final HTML? Further I put it in a new window:

```
        this.OpenWindow = window.open('', 'childwindow', 'width=800,height=400,left=150,top=200');
        this.OpenWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "";
        this.OpenWindow.document.body.appendChild(componentRef.location.nativeElement);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day!

You probably do the right things, but:

1. You don't need `ng-container`, just remove it
2. Mark data as input property of `TransitionPrintComponent` (`@Input() data;`)
3. Inject `ViewContainerRef` in your component, where you try to create an instance of `TransitionPrintComponent`. And try this code snippet:

```
const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(TransitionPrintComponent);
const componentRef = this.vcr.create(componentFactory);
componentRef.instance.data = relocateDoc;

console.log(componentRef.location.nativeElement);
```

Here the link, so you can get more details: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#resolving-components

Hope it helps ;)